# Not sure how to develop two methods for this code

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need the first method for generating a random number should receive the beginning and ending value of the range within its parameter list.  It should send back the random number through the method name. And the second method to display the array which I have but apparently the code is not broken down into two methods and I don't understand how to accomplish this. I am lost after working on this for so long.

Here is my UPDATED code but still receiving 4 errors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public final class  {
  public static Random generator = new Random();
     public int createNum(int[] randomNumbers, int SIZE, int n, int i) {

    int x;
    SIZE = 20;
    randomNumbers = new int[SIZE];


        Random generator = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        n = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;   
            randomNumbers[i] = n;
            }
            return n;
        }
        public void print(int i, int randomNumbers, int SIZE){
        SIZE = 20;
        randomNumbers = new int[SIZE];

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
        do{
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you wish to restart the program, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");            
        x = inputReader.nextInt();
    } while (x == 1);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first, don't put everything in `main` if the task is to decompose your solution. What you need is a class that exercises the logic of your requirements or at least two additional methods that perform the work independently.

This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    int n = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
    randomNumbers[i] = n;
}

for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
}
```

represents two distinct tasks. You can tell because they are not dependent on each other.

This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    int n = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
    randomNumbers[i] = n;
}
```

generates and places the numbers.

This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
}
```

prints them.

Since it seems beneficial for you to figure this out on your own; what's needed now? *hint: read the first part again*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by read the first part?@ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: The beginning of my post explains what you would need to do. The code in my post is arranged such that with a little thought I'm sure you will have no trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Alright this is what I have come up with so far but am still receiving errors@ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: @kidbone, always list the errors you're getting and format your code to be more readable.